# Custom diagram design using Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

This question is a little left-of-field. I'm looking to generate a custom figure using data of the form:

| Source Type | Target Type | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S-A | T-B | 1.52 |
| S-C | T-C | 11.18 |
| S-B | T-A | 21.31 |
| S-D | T-A | 12.63 |
| S-C | T-D | 7.92 |

- Each of the first two columns contains four labels, either as strings or integers.
- The final column is numeric.
- This file may contain several hundred rows.

I wish to generate a figure similar to the following (e.g. approximated from the table above):

[image: The approximate figure generated from the Table shown above.]

The figure shows that `S-A` goes to `T-B` *quickly*: in 1.52 minutes. The height of all `T-X` bars is the maximum value in the `time` column. The point at which the arc from `S-A` intersects `T-B` is at 1.52 minutes.

Is this possible in Latex or another software package/platform? Ideally, I would also be able to style the figure. Most importantly, change the colours of the boxes and arcs. I am open to alternative figure templates if they convey the same information *without* interaction.

I've done quite some research, finding the likes of [Flourish](https://flourish.studio/), but cannot seem to find something suitable for this use case.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far?

Comment: Thank you! In Latex, I don't even know where to start, sorry - not without explicitly typing each data point as an edge.

Comment: If I correctly understand your comment, than use of LaTeX is no way to go.

Comment: I've been proven wrong before! Feel free to delete the question if it's not possible, though.

Comment: Well. that isonly my opinion, maybe someone else have different opinion and see a way how todo this with (Lua)LaTeX.

Comment: This question contains multiple problems: 1. Reading a file. 2. Finding the right positions for the `T-` nodes. 3. How should that look with hundreds of `S-` and `T-` nodes? Or will it only contain at max 20 `T-` and `S-` types?

Comment: That is a good point, @Qrrbrbirlbel, thank you. I intend this to be limited to `n` type-`T-` nodes and `m` type-`S-` nodes, where `n` and `m` are less than ~10. But you're right, it's not an easy problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A starting point could be the following, which can be probably automated even further:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newlength\targetmaxheight
\setlength{\targetmaxheight}{3cm}

\newcounter{targetmaxvalue}
\setcounter{targetmaxvalue}{25}

\newlength\targetxsep
\newlength\targetysep
\setlength{\targetxsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\targetysep}{-.25cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    source/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes={
            draw
        }
    },
    target/.style={
        draw,
        minimum width=1cm,
        minimum height=\targetmaxheight,
    }
]

\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\foreach \s in {S-A,S-B,S-C,S-D}{%
    \xappto\mymatrixcontent{ \s \\ }
}%

\node[source] at (0,0) (s) { 
    \mymatrixcontent
};

\node[target, above left=\targetysep and \targetxsep of s] (t-1) { T-A };
\node[target, above right=\targetysep and \targetxsep of s] (t-2) { T-B };
\node[target, below right=\targetysep and \targetxsep of s] (t-3) { T-C };
\node[target, below left=\targetysep and \targetxsep of s] (t-4) { T-D };

\draw (s-2-1) to[in=0, out=180] ([yshift={\targetmaxheight*(21.31/\value{targetmaxvalue})}]t-1.south east);
\draw (s-1-1) to[in=180, out=0] ([yshift={\targetmaxheight*(1.52/\value{targetmaxvalue})}]t-2.south west);
\draw (s-3-1) to[in=180, out=0] ([yshift={\targetmaxheight*(11.18/\value{targetmaxvalue})}]t-3.south west);
\draw (s-4-1) to[in=0, out=180] ([yshift={\targetmaxheight*(12.63/\value{targetmaxvalue})}]t-1.south east);
\draw (s-3-1) to[in=0, out=180] ([yshift={\targetmaxheight*(7.92/\value{targetmaxvalue})}]t-4.south east);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With a bit more automation (probably not the most elegant way to do this):

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newlength\targetmaxheight
\setlength{\targetmaxheight}{3cm}

\newcounter{targetmaxvalue}
\setcounter{targetmaxvalue}{25}

\newlength\targetxsep
\newlength\targetysep
\setlength{\targetxsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\targetysep}{-.25cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance={
        \targetysep and \targetxsep
    },
    source/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes={
            draw
        }
    },
    target/.style={
        draw,
        minimum width=1cm,
        minimum height=\targetmaxheight,
    },
    connect/.code args={(#1) to (#2) at #3}{
        \path (#1);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\tempsx}{\tempsy}
        \path (#2);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\temptx}{\tempty}
        \draw (#1) to[
            in={\ifdim\tempsx<\temptx 180\else 0\fi}, 
            out={\ifdim\tempsx<\temptx 0\else 180\fi}
        ] ([yshift={\targetmaxheight*(#3/\value{targetmaxvalue})}]#2.south \ifdim\tempsx<\temptx west\else east\fi);
    }
]

\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\foreach \s in {S-A,S-B,S-C,S-D}{%
    \xappto\mymatrixcontent{ \s \\ }
}%

\node[source] at (0,0) (s) { 
    \mymatrixcontent
};

\node[target, above left=of s] (t-1) { T-A };
\node[target, above right=of s] (t-2) { T-B };
\node[target, below right=of s] (t-3) { T-C };
\node[target, below left=of s] (t-4) { T-D };

\path[connect={(s-2-1) to (t-1) at 21.31}];
\path[connect={(s-1-1) to (t-2) at 1.52}];
\path[connect={(s-3-1) to (t-3) at 11.18}];
\path[connect={(s-4-1) to (t-1) at 12.63}];
\path[connect={(s-3-1) to (t-4) at 7.92}];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result looks the same as above.

Comment: The [`rectangle split` shape](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.rectangle:split) has anchors for each part.

Comment: Woah - I had given up on someone being able to do this. Well done, and thank you!